# BundleTable error with new ASP.NET MVC 4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I get this error when running any new ASP.NET MVC 4 project:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type
>   'System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable' exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
>   and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\05fd41d4\f4dfecc4\assembly\dl3\1577f2c6\e8fef103_d1f6cc01\System.Web.Optimization.DLL'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview installed (this is where `System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable` in `System.Web.dll` is coming from) and ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta is not compatible with it (you can read release notes here: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes)